# How do I access an object via another object that contains an object which is a property of the object I want to have access to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, prototype

It was kinda hard to come up with the title for this one, hope it's understandable and makes sense.

Well , maybe, the difficulty to come up with the title reflects some unnecessary complexity of this situation - if there's a simple way to do this I'd love to know.

In this sample, there's a Car 'class', from which I can instance objects (Cars). It has a template (an SVG, which is not a car, actually, but who cares), and also public methods, used to modify the template, via jQuery.

In the carContainerClick() function, how do I access the Car instance whose template is contained by the currently clicked carContainer element?

[Sample here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YH5zAGWMQaKTr7DpXLej?p=preview)

```
$(function(){

  var cars = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    var carContainer = $('<div/>', { class: 'car-container'});
    var car = new Car();

    cars[i] = car;

    carContainer.on('click', carContainerClick);

    carContainer.append(car.getTemplate());
    $('.container').append(carContainer);
  }

  function carContainerClick() {

    // HERE - how do I access the Car instance whose template is contained by the currently clicked carContainer element?

    cars[0].changeColor();
  }
});

function Car () {
  this.template = $('<svg viewBox="0 0 301 259">    <g class="svg-group"><path class="stick-2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M74.192,27.447c2.589-2.042,4.576-3.188,6.991-5.093c0,0,1.753-1.11,0.416-2.945 c-1.13-1.546-3.242,0.014-3.242,0.014c-4.831,3.804-9.678,7.589-14.491,11.418c-2.335,1.861-4.335,4.009-7.954,3.233 c-2.136-0.458-3.892,1.798-3.913,4.021c-0.02,2.326,1.531,4.107,3.734,4.296c2.353,0.2,4.689-1.183,4.635-3.241    c-0.066-2.415,1.215-3.474,2.981-4.492c1.821-1.049,5.809-3.993,7.21-4.785C71.961,29.082,74.192,27.447,74.192,27.447z"/></g></svg>');
}

Car.prototype = {
  getTemplate: function() {
    return this.template;
  },
  changeColor: function() {
    console.log('changeColor');
    $('.svg-group', this.template).find("path, polygon, circle").attr("fill", "#aff");
  }
};
```

**update**

i made a little [test](http://jsperf.com/loopclosures) with the solutions provided here and turns out it makes almost no difference in performance .. but i like the IIFE one for its simplicity. [Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/3wsFXPnYDjOYMXuwSmsg?p=info)

Comment: no, that title is actually really confusing, can you rephrase it?

Comment: i'm thinking about it. any suggestions?

Comment: Did you consider adding an onclick handler to each car instead of the container?

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed by the title. Can you edit to use the word "object" a few more times to clarify?

Comment: @zok, I added letters to your title and end up with "How do I access an object A via another object B that contains an object C which is a property of the object A I want to have access to?". So clearly that doesn't make sense. Start with "given objects A and B, how do I ..." and take it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inline function as your event handler that passes `car` as a parameter... however, because the `car` declaration is hoisted out of your loop (specifically to the top of the current function), you need to ensure that the event handler captures the right `Car` instance, and not the last one to pass through the loop.

You can create a closure by using a self invoking function expression that creates a new scope for `car` that exists *within* the loop and allows the *right* car instance to be captured when you set up your handler.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    (function(){
      var carContainer = $('<div/>', { class: 'car-container'});
      var car = new Car();
      cars[i] = car;
      carContainer.on('click', function(){
        carContainerClick(car);
      });
      carContainer.append(car.getTemplate());
      $('.container').append(carContainer);
    })();
  }
```

Now you can have a function that gets handed the `Car` instance you need.

```
  function carContainerClick(car) {
    car.changeColor();
  }
```

Comment: it was tricky to understand why it captures the last car instance... [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) has some good explanations! not sure which one is better, to use an IFEE or to declare the function that binds `car` and `carContainer` as @Volune   did

Answer (score 1):

Use [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to pass the car instance as an argument to the `carContainerClick` function.

I extracted a new function, cause doing that stuff in a for loop will probably not work (always passing the last car as an argument)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var carContainer = $('<div/>', { class: 'car-container'});
    var car = new Car();

    cars[i] = car;

    bindCarContainer(carContainer, car);

    carContainer.append(car.getTemplate());
    $('.container').append(carContainer);
}

function bindCarContainer(carContainer, car) {
    carContainer.on('click', function(event) {
        carContainerClick.call(this, car, event);
    });
}

function carContainerClick(car, event) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: great solution! not sure which one is more readable or has better performance though.. between this one and the IIFE-wrapping one from @spender. in addition, it also works without using `.call()`...is there any particular reason to use it?

Comment: Just do be compatible with the `$(this)` lots of people do in event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning storing it in a property:

```
$container = $('.container');
for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    var car = new Car(),
        carContainer = $('<div/>').addClass('car-container').prop('car', car);
    carContainer.on('click', carContainerClick);
    carContainer.append(car.getTemplate());
    $container.append(carContainer);
}

function carContainerClick() {
    this.car.changeColor();
}

var $template = $('<svg viewBox="0 0 301 259">    <g class="svg-group"><path class="stick-2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M74.192,27.447c2.589-2.042,4.576-3.188,6.991-5.093c0,0,1.753-1.11,0.416-2.945 c-1.13-1.546-3.242,0.014-3.242,0.014c-4.831,3.804-9.678,7.589-14.491,11.418c-2.335,1.861-4.335,4.009-7.954,3.233 c-2.136-0.458-3.892,1.798-3.913,4.021c-0.02,2.326,1.531,4.107,3.734,4.296c2.353,0.2,4.689-1.183,4.635-3.241    c-0.066-2.415,1.215-3.474,2.981-4.492c1.821-1.049,5.809-3.993,7.21-4.785C71.961,29.082,74.192,27.447,74.192,27.447z"/></g></svg>');

function Car () {
    this.$template = $template.clone();
}

Car.prototype = {
    getTemplate: function() {
        return this.$template;
    },
    changeColor: function() {
        console.log('changeColor');
        $('.svg-group', this.$template).find("path, polygon, circle").attr("fill", "#aff");
    }
};
```

Some notes:

- Don't use `$` to get elements inside a loop, it's very slow! Store the result in a variable before the loop instead
- `{ class: 'car-container'}` may fail on old browsers because `class` was reserved. Try `'class'` with quotes or `addClass` method.
- To remember what is a DOM element and what is a jQuery wrapper, you can use `$` at the beginning of the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.data()` to attach a reference to the car to the template:

```
function Car () {
    this.template = $('<svg viewBox="0 0 301 259">    <g class="svg-group"><path class="stick-2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M74.192,27.447c2.589-2.042,4.576-3.188,6.991-5.093c0,0,1.753-1.11,0.416-2.945 c-1.13-1.546-3.242,0.014-3.242,0.014c-4.831,3.804-9.678,7.589-14.491,11.418c-2.335,1.861-4.335,4.009-7.954,3.233 c-2.136-0.458-3.892,1.798-3.913,4.021c-0.02,2.326,1.531,4.107,3.734,4.296c2.353,0.2,4.689-1.183,4.635-3.241    c-0.066-2.415,1.215-3.474,2.981-4.492c1.821-1.049,5.809-3.993,7.21-4.785C71.961,29.082,74.192,27.447,74.192,27.447z"/></g></svg>');
    this.template.data('car', this);
}
```

Then later you can access it from the jQuery object:

```
function carContainerClick() {
    var car = this.data('car');
    car.changeColor();
}
```